# Getting rendered html from a React component in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a function in my react component, which is returning another component

```
const getWidget = () => {
    return (
        <Widget
            useVariant={'1'}
       />
    )
}
const widgetCode = getWidget()
return (<div>
    CDE
    {widgetCode}
  </div>
)
```

Here is the code for the Widget component

```
const Widget = (useVariant) => {
   if(useVariant == '1') {
      return (<div>
          ABC
      </div>)
   } else {
     return (<div>
          DEF
      </div>)
   }
}
```

When I call getWidget() function I want to have rendered HTML which will be returned by the Widget component. But what I get is [Object object]. Just want to understand how I can get rendered HTML. So I am expecting the below-mentioned return value

```
 <div>
      ABC
 </div>
```

Comment: In what context will you be calling `getWidget()`? Can you post the code for your `<Widget />` component?

Comment: How are you calling getWidget()?

Comment: What returns `[Object object]`? The component or `useVariant`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const getWidget = () => {
  return <Widget useVariant={"1"} />;
};

const Widget = ({useVariant}) => {
  if (useVariant == "1") {
    return <div>ABC</div>;
  } else {
    return <div>DEF</div>;
  }
};

function Login() {
  const widgetCode = getWidget()
  return (
    <>
     {widgetCode}
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```